# mantis bug reporting timeout

Tags: timeout, mantis

When I report a bug in our Mantis system I sometimes take too long to enter all the info (>5 min) and Mantis reports a timeout when I finally hit the "Submit report" button.
Hitting BACK doesn't always work, either I lose everything I have typed or resubmitting still doesn't work (same error).

Question: why is this "feature" there and is there a way to either disable it or make it (a lot) longer timeout?

We're using Mantis 1.2.3

Comment: Using HTTP as in HTTP://mantis.mycompany.com.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that by 'Mantis reports a timeout' you mean *APPLICATION ERROR #2800: Invalid form security token. This could be caused by a session timeout, or accidentally submitting the form twice.*, then most likely the issue is caused by a PHP session timeout.

Please refer to the corresponding [troubleshooting section in the MantisBT Administrator's guide](https://www.mantisbt.org/docs/master/en-US/Admin_Guide/html-desktop/#admin.troubleshooting.errors.2800).

As a workaround, the Administrator can increase the value of [session.gc_maxlifetime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php), or set `$g_form_security_validation = OFF;` in config_inc.php (not recommended for security reasons).

Comment: Link is no longer valid.  Pretty sure the policy for answers is to summarize key information from links so when the link expires there is still an answer.

Comment: @kbulgrien thanks for your comment, I have improved the answer and fixed the broken link.

Answer (score 0):

you must to set security_validation in OFF :
    $g_form_security_validation = OFF;

Comment: This would work, but it is not recommended for security reasons, as it leaves MantisBT open to CSRF attacks.